# Got an JavaScript object instead of a MediaStream object

Tags: javascript, object, webrtc

My problem is that I get a JavaScript object instead of a MediaStream object.
That wouldn't be a big problem if the addStream method would allow JavaScript objects, too.
The JavaScript object owns the same attributes as a MediaStream object.

The question is now: Is there a way to create a new MediaStream object with the attributes of the JavaScript object or to cast the JavaScript object to a MediaStream object?

The exact error of the console: 
"Uncaught Type Error: Failed to execute 'addStream' on 'RTCPeerConnection': parameter 1 is not of type 'MediaStream'."

EDIT:
I took two screenshots of the MediaStream object before sending as JSON and the recieved object, which should be a MediaStream object, too.
[MediaStream Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asiu2.jpg) [JavaScript Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWbUX.jpg)

Comment: At what callback do you get the object and not the stream? What process causes this?

Comment: I get a JSON object from a remote client, which includes the information about the type of the message (for example sdpOffer or adpAnswer), the sdp data and the MediaStream. But the JSON object isn't type of MediaStream anymore.

So if I want to use the addStream method I get the console error which you can read above.

Comment: Why are you sending the MediaStream object over JSON? The other computer would not be able to play the stream anyways even if it could be transformed from a JSON object into a MediaStream one.

Comment: The goal of the project is adding mediastream to PlayRTC. The specification wants that it communicates via JSON. [link](https://github.com/atamborrino/PlayRTC)

Comment: Does it say specifically to send MediaStream objects this way or allow the RTCPeerConnection created to handle it?

Comment: There is a handshake which works through JSON and the offer-message, which is the JSON object, shall include the id of the offerer,the sdp and the stream. The reason for this is that the clients have to do the handshake through a server and then start to connect directly. I hope you understand what I try to explain. If not just ask.

Comment: Well, WebRTC was not designed that way and I have never heard of a project demanding the MediaStream object be passed between the peers...Interesting I suppose.

Comment: I added two screenshots to my first post to show better my problem.

Comment: You cannot create a new media stream object from a JSON object. I am not sure why it needs to be pushed over JSON but it will not work from all that I have read and experienced.